# Imposing a constraint on derivative when fitting of a polynomial

Tags: regression, constrained-regression

I have experimental 2D data $ (x_i,y_i)$ that is used to fit a polynomial.
$$
y = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k
$$

I am using the GSL library, using the [linear fitting API](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html).
It does usually well however in some situations, I get an inversion of the slope of the polynomial, and **I know** that this cannot be.

I am looking for a way to add some constraint to the fitting process: shortly, I want to state that the derivative of the polynomial is always positive.

I am not a mathematician, so my questions are:

- Is there some known mathematical tool to do this ?
- practically, does GSL provides such algorithm ? (I mean, I can read the manual, but I don't really know where to look)

**Edit**: To clarify my needs, the data is normalized in a range so that $x \in [0:1]$. What happens with the polynomial outside of this range has no importance, as the data will always stay in this range.

**Edit 2**: this question has been suggested as a dupe. I am not able to have an strong opinion on the fact that it is a dupe or not, due to a lack of mathematical background. However, I can clarify the question: what I was looking for is a way to fit data to a polynomial with the additional constraint:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \; a_k \; x^{k-1} > 0
$$

Comment: Closely related threads can be found by searching [constrained regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=constrained+regression). It looks like none of them answer this question because (a) most of the answers involve little tricks specific to their circumstances, rather than general solutions, and (b) all of them concern equality constraints rather than inequality constraints. However, **this question is ambiguous:** (1) Why did you use different subscripts $i$ and $j$ to describe your data? (2) Does the slope need to be positive *at all real numbers* or just at the $\{x_i\}$?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. The i vs j was just a typo, and I edited the question to clarify my requirements. Oh, and I usually have x-values that cover the whole range.

Comment: Interestingly, this question has a good answer back on the math site at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/polynomial-fitting-where-polynomial-must-be-monotonically-increasing.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I also saw that one afterwards. But I am afraid I don't have the required background to understand it: I never have heard before of Semidefinite programming. I will try to find some time to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming ! But shall I consider that GSL does not provide such constrained optimisation algorithm ?

Comment: I took a quick glance at the GSL documentation and based on what it offers I would presume it cannot do anything like what you ask. It may be worth remarking that what you are attempting is unusual and might be inferior to other procedures. Perhaps you might like to consider modifying your post: describe your data and what you would like to learn from them, then let readers suggest appropriate procedures.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your help, I will consider this. Maybe you could post this as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit monotone polynomial to data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156327/fit-monotone-polynomial-to-data)