# Fit monotone polynomial to data

Tags: python, fitting, polynomial, isotonic

I want to fit monotone polynomials to data. Murray, Müller and Turlach (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00180-012-0390-5) provide an implementation in R (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonoPoly/index.html) of their algorithm.

I'm looking for an implementations in python (scipy et al.). To make the question more general, is it me or is fitting of monotone polynomials rarely supported?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky but you could use [isotonic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_isotonic_regression.html) followed by [piecewise cubic Hermite interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.pchip_interpolate.html#scipy.interpolate.pchip_interpolate).

Comment: What is the use of cubic interpolation after regression? Can you give an example

Comment: This is what I also found in the literature, but I want a parametrized function because i need to take measurement uncertainties into account during a fit. Interpolation is therefore not an option.

Comment: @Somebody If measurement uncertainties are your main concern, you don't need a monotone polynomial fit; existing tools for nonparametric monotone regression will suffice. You can account for measurement uncertainties with weighted isotonic regression, [which is supported in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/isotonic.html). You just set the weights w_i = 1/sigma_i^2 where sigma_i is the error of measurement i.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is no reason to believe that the resulting cubic spline will *necessarily* be monotonic. In that light, there's not much advantage to just fitting the cubic spline directly to the data.

Comment: Actually pchip interpolation is guaranteed monotonic when the input data is monotonic. That's why I suggested preprocessing with isotonic regression. Read this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html